# Como selecionar apenas os caracteres que eu quero de uma fonte?

Tags: desempenho, font-awesome

Eu gostaria de diminuir o tamanho em disco da fonte para que a página carregue mais rápido. É a fonte de ícones Font Awesome. Eu quero saber se há alguma ferramenta para que eu possa remover os caracteres que eu não utilizo e deixar a fonte mais "enxuta".

Por exemplo, se eu só utilizo os ícones de redes sociais, tem como eu remover todos os outros ícones da fonte de forma que fiquem só os que eu utilizo, e assim, deixando mais leve o arquivo a ser carregado pelo cliente?

Comment: Também queria saber :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O [icomoon.io](https://icomoon.io/app/#/select) permite que selecione caracteres e gere uma nova fonte a partir deles facilmente.

[image]

Basta importar o Font Awesome clicando no ícone da biblioteca e procurar por ele, selecionar os ícones que utilizará e clicar em Generate Font.

Ele fará o download de um .zip, descompacte-o e vá na pasta fonts, onde encontrará o arquivo icomoon.ttf.

[image]

Além do formato .ttf, ele exportará em .eot, .svg e .woff.

Answer (score 1):

O que você procura deverá ser, na minha opinião o [IcoMoon](http://icomoon.io/app). :)

No IcoMoon, pode escolher quais os icons que precisa/quer ou até mesmo importar no site (ou procurar na galeira do site) e mais tarde fazer download do novo `font-style`.

Também pode mudar a `class` de cada icons para a sua preferência (mas o valor predefinido é o da fonte original).

Espero que seja uma boa ajuda!